# Where can I find a simple but complete taxonomy of churches?

Tags: church-history

I'm looking for a simple but complete taxonomy of churches.

I'd like something that is more detailed than this one I found on Wikipedia (in particular showing the branches of Eastern and Oriental Orthodoxy):

[image]

But less detailed/messy than this one, which goes into rather too much detail for the Protestant churches, while perhaps neglecting some of the other churches.

[image]

Comment: The former is a timeline; the latter is a web.

Comment: I could also use one. Good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps too detailed for your needs but this one is amazing:

[image]

The full-quality version loads dynamically [here](http://funki.com.ua/ru/portfolio/lab/world-religions-tree/).